# Objective-C Predicate Element starts with $

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I tried to use predicate to find in array into `"title"` property the subelement `"$t"`.

```
filterPlaces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:youtubeChannelWS.youtubeArrayVideos];
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title.$t contains[cd] %@", placeName];
[filterPlaces filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But I received an error that it's not find the variable t.

Do you know how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What exactly is the scenario? Can you please explain with an example array and place name? and the expected output after predicate?

Comment: Could it be that you need to escape the `$`? "`\$`"

Comment: Does your title object have a property called $t?

Comment: escape $ or the predicate parser thinks it is a predicate format variable. then look if there even is a property $t .. weird name

Comment: Just remove the $'s from you property names!